# No incompatible operands

Tags: typescript

I want the follow equality expression to fail:

```
class C1 {
    static readonly X = new C1;
}
class C2 {
    static readonly X = new C2;
}
C1.X === C2.X;
```

TypeScript does not report any error on it. Is there an option to cause an error such as:

> Comparison between incompatible types: C1 and C2

?

Comment: Those are structurally identical types and thus comparable; perhaps you want to make them differ in some structural way like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLXaZm) shows?  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I didn't think of that; yes, that solves the issue. I thought only `interface`s and `type` aliases were structurally compared the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) instance types, like all types, are (generally) compared [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).

---

Given

```
class C1 {
    static readonly X = new C1;
}
class C2 {
    static readonly X = new C2;
}
```

the instance types `C1` and `C2` have no structure apart from being object-like.  They don't have any members (the `static` members of the class constructor are not members of the instance types)  So they are equivalent to the empty object type `{}` and therefore to each other.  That means `C1.X` and `C2.X` are both of the same type, and `C1.X === C2.X` will be allowed.  [Empty classes are known to behave "strangely"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).

---

If you want them to be considered incompatible types, you should give them incompatible structure.  The easiest way to do that is to give them members of different types.  Perhaps they can each have a `name` property of a distinct [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), as shown here:

```
class C1 {
  static readonly X = new C1;
  readonly name = "C1";
  // (property) C1.name: "C1"
}
class C2 {
  static readonly X = new C2;
  readonly name = "C2";
  // (property) C2.name: "C2"
}

C1.X === C2.X; // error! 
// This comparison appears to be unintentional 
// because the types 'C1' and 'C2' have no overlap.
```

By making the `name` property [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly) the compiler infers a literal type like `"C1"` or `"C2"` from the initializer instead of just `string` (which would not distinguish them).

---

Another way to do this is to give them both [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) or [`protected`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#protected) properties, which [makes them incompatible even if they have the same shape](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes).  That is, `private`/`protected` properties will make a `class` instance type behave [nominally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) instead of structurally:

```
class C1 {
  static readonly X = new C1;
  private prop?: undefined;

}
class C2 {
  static readonly X = new C2;
  private prop?: undefined;
}
C1.X === C2.X; // error! 
// This comparison appears to be unintentional 
// because the types 'C1' and 'C2' have no overlap.
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARAlgMwwBQE4HsYkBvAKCSXgBsQookBhARhPIqSgBcRO14lcEEABN8wKgE8kADSQBeJMAgB3RkwDcbCoJFjJi8MgUAiZsc3skAeitIAFDAIwIuThICUagHShIALiRTJmM2AF82alp6BgAmVksuHj4BIVFxKVkFJVVYi3YdNP1fI0DY8y1rWwcnFzdPWJ9DANMYkIpwimYvTLkFBuk8myQAFQALNHp4fDA4XAmxJBAYZxBcek58JAAjZABXYDRgTggjtDEQKiQ2IZ34EF2oZE5Rp4lnegByZg-F4GEkL4xH6jEAAN2QwE2+HBuBoMC8pHCpGKsAQyDwaFBPAgeEI8UoNDoanxFESvH4BT0GXkihUajyFEcmOxSEchAA-AF9sIIBhDhBhJowhFCdE4mQEtxySldOkZDTsowYgzWXMscdVRyuX9efzBcLOkxuvJekruoNbGMJpRprN5sBFsshGskBttnsDkcTrxzlRrrZbvdHq6Xq63tAAd9fv9AcCwRCoTC4QjEUA)